# Observer subscribe pattern in blog

Tags: javascript

I've been reading this blog https://blog.lftechnology.com/implementing-the-observer-pattern-in-javascript-198ccb62124d and couldn't figure out the following piece of code:
The `return` statement here:

```
return () =>
      (this.subscribers = this.subscribers.filter(
        subscriber => subscriber !== fn
      ));
```

inside this piece of code:

```
subscribe(fn) {
    if (Array.isArray(fn)) {
      return this.subscribeMany(fn);
    }

    this.subscribers.push(fn);

    return () =>
      (this.subscribers = this.subscribers.filter(
        subscriber => subscriber !== fn
      ));
  }
```

Should this be removed altogether rather than `subscriber => subscriber !== fn` as indicated? They just pushed the value `fn` to `this.subscribers` in the previous line and then remove it immediately? it doesn't make sense.

Comment: The function that removes `fn` is returned, not called.

Comment: Yes, that's correct! However, isn't it weird to return an anonymous function that filter out the subscribers after it's subscribed? it seems like this is an unsubscribe function, and in that case it would be like this: 

```return { unsubscribe() =>
      (this.subscribers = this.subscribers.filter(
        subscriber => subscriber !== fn
      ))
};```

Comment: it seems like this return is only used to enable chaining? @Ry- and serves no useful purpose

Comment: It is an unsubscribe function, and there’s no particular reason it would be like that vs. how it’s already written. There’s nothing to chain, and if you just mean immediately calling something on the result, you would never do that (immediately call `.unsubscribe()` on the return value of `.subscribe()`).

Answer (score 0):

Subscribing to an observable returns a `Subscription` object which has an `unsubscribe()` method that takes no argument and just disposes the resource held by the subscription.